# In saltstack what is the best place to store data

Tags: salt-stack

In salt what is best practice in storing data is it pillar, grain, maps, mine, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one rule fits for all. Here is how we use in our company.

If the data need to be stored at one place and not to be shared across minions we use Pillar. (pillar data is stored in-memory on Minion (never it touches disk))

If the data is not that sensitive we can use maps in the state.tls files (by this we save some memory on Minion)(not storing in minion).

If data need to be stored at one place and Minion can send commands to update, etc Grains could do that.

Mine we use when we want to access/share data across all minions.

Hope this helps

Regards
Sudhakar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very useful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWhvgLqgYR0&t=566s) about best practices in saltstack.
Most of the data can be stored in pillar, but the structure of your pillar is very important.
You can categorise your pillar by `region`, `roles`, `grains`.
For example, you might want to share some pillar across `region1`, some other pillar for all web servers, some pillar only for a certain type of operating system.

I find it so nice and flexible!